# Docker - how to cache added directory?

Tags: java, docker

Basically I have a bunch of thirdparty jar files from gradle build which are copied to `external` directory.
Those jars almost never change, but Docker somehow does not want to cache that layer.

My Docker file is pretty simplistic:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY app.jar .
COPY project /opt/app/project
COPY external /opt/app/external
EXPOSE 2550 7000
```

The `md5sum` of all `jar` files and sizes in that `external` directory are identical. The `stat` only shows that `inode` is different on those files (expect for file times of course, but according to docker docs mtime is ignored when comparing) .

Yet if I look at docker history, I see that the layer is not cached:

tag: test-1

```
1be1e9a7084b        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 2550/tcp 7000/tcp     0B
e593cf804634        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:b2ed14f41affcee...   60.4MB
a55be55e6e68        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f1abbe11a6a64fe...   566kB
e8823ec84dfb        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:ba5ef09e42eda4...   523kB
041f6f6957b5        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /opt/app              0B
15e4c78e545c        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /opt/app                    0B
```

tag: test-2

```
aacb13926d18        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 2550/tcp 7000/tcp     0B
7ebe12849fad        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:b2ed14f41affcee...   60.4MB
4bf898283d11        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f1abbe11a6a64fe...   566kB
886630b2a05a        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5ad60a31d9e72d...   523kB
041f6f6957b5        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /opt/app              0B
15e4c78e545c        17 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /opt/app                    0B
```

So how I can force docker to reuse a layer with those thirdparty jars that almost never change? 
Is it because the external directory is recreated everytime after build? Ar there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the COPY external /opt/app/external layer to the top, as first COPY statement. If one Docker layer has changed, the follwoing layers will be invalidated. Move your most static COPYs and commands to the top and the frequently changing commands to the bottom of your Dockerfile.